# How to make the smartphone work as a pc monitor?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I am have a pc and recently my dell monitor stopped working so i had called up the customer careband they said that they will get it replaced within a week. So till that time i can't use the pc (OS is Windows 10) so is there any way to use my rooted android phone (running 4.3, jelly bean) as a temporary monitor as my pc is working perfect but i have no display. Note that i can't install any softwares on the pc as i don't have a display. I only have a phone, wifi network and usb option. Is there any way that i can achieve this without installing any software on the pc just using the phone and installing some app on the phone? I hope for a good response

Comment: No you cannot, there is no video input to the phone for using the screen.

Comment: I doubt this is possible... Any solution, like Splashtop or Air Display 2, will not work as it requires installing software on the PC prior to use.

Comment: Also, I don't know where you live, but around here it is not uncommon to find local classified ads of monitors for sale very cheaply... 20" LCD monitors can be had used for under $20 and older, tube-style monitors are often give-away items. They could get you through for a short time.

Answer (score -1):

you will need to do it in 2 steps, first get a remote desktop client for your phone in order to connect to your pc, then once that is done, install pc software for that purpose (http://www.kainy.com/download.html)  , after that, install the phone software https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kainy.clientads

Comment: The OP specifically stated that installing software on the PC was not possible.

Answer (score -3):

If you have Remote Desktop enabled you can use a Remote Desktop software to access it.  Unfortunately, it isn't on by default.

Can you use another display?  Many TVs have a VGA port on them.  Perhaps visit someone with a monitor?